# Authorize in my app as salesforce user

Tags: api, c#

I have an asp.net website.
I want to give an access to my website to the users, that are already authenticated in salesforce.
According to the tutorials, i should use OAuth or something similar, but i can't find any code or examples how to realize this.

In fact, when user enters my website, all info that i need is :

1)He is really authenticated by salesforce

2)His username

Comment: I think you will need to set up SSO betweeen your site and Salesforce ?

Comment: Can you please provide an example?! I dont want to implement thousands of steps to get only two criterias about a user : username and log_in_status, so, there might be an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an iframe within a salesforce tab, what you're looking for is [Canvas](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/canvas_framework.pdf). This can give you a Signed Request or an OAuth request, which both have different mechanisms but behave essentially the same-- salesforce provides you with a token that you can use to automatically login to salesforce. Depending on the canvas app's "scope", you can control which pieces of data the app can realize (e.g. id provides basic user info, chatter lets you read/post chatter messages, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You want to enable Salesforce as an Identity Provider ?

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&language=en

Comment: Not at all. I have an iFrame on salesforce , that leads to my website. So, i want my website to get current salesforce user's username. Then i will check, if such user really exists and automatically authorize him on my website. The thing i don't know is how to get two these properties